# Get all required bundles in Java

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

How can I get all required bundles defined in manifest.mf file, as java `org.osgi.framework.Bundle` objects ?

I need these bundles for BundleWiring

Comment: Not sure what you want. Do you mean you have deployed your bundles at runtime and want to see all bundles that are required by a certain bundle?

Comment: Something like that

Answer (score 2):

You can get the [BundleWiring](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html) for your current bundle:

```
 wiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class)
```

From the wiring you can then get the requird wires for example for the package namespace.

```
wires = wiring.getRequiredWires(...)
```

From the wires you can get the BundleRevision that provides the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The OSGi specification has example code exactly for this case.
Here is the code:

```
void printImports( Bundle A ) {
    BundleWiring wA = A.adapt( BundleWiring.class );
    for ( BundleWire wire :
     wA.getRequiredWires(PACKAGE_NAMESPACE)) {
     String pack = (String) wire.getCapability().getAttributes()
         .get(PACKAGE_NAMESPACE);
     Bundle bundle = wire.getProviderWiring()
          .getBundle());
     System.out.println(pack + " - " + bundle.getLocation());
    }
}
```

Retrieved from https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.wiring.html#i1748298